# Convert from irregular frequency to monthly within groupby objects in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df containing userid, date of observation (usually quarterly frequency, but could be irregular) and a characteristic value, for example:

```
from util.Dates import Dates, to_date
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
     RefIssuerId=[11590] * 3 + [115948] * 4,
     AvailableDate=[to_date(d) for d in (20050613, 20050905, 20051214,
                    20040924, 20041101, 20050202,20050516)],
      Characteristic=[0.06, 0.09, 0.07, 0.13, 0.09, 0.06, 0.04]))

UserID     Date    Characteristic
115950  6/13/2005   0.06
115950  9/5/2005    0.09
115950  12/14/2005  0.07
115948  9/24/2004   0.13
115948  11/1/2004   0.09
115948  2/2/2005    0.06
115948  5/16/2005   0.04
```

I am trying to upsample it to monthly frequency *within* userid groups. That is, looking to get smth like this (sorted by userid and date)

```
UserID  Date    Characteristic  month_date
115950  6/13/2005   0.06    6/30/2005
115950  6/13/2005   0.06    7/31/2005
115950  6/13/2005   0.06    8/31/2005
115950  9/5/2005    0.09    9/30/2005
115950  9/5/2005    0.09    10/31/2005
115950  9/5/2005    0.09    11/30/2005
115950  12/14/2005  0.07    12/31/2005
115950  12/14/2005  0.07    1/31/2006
115950  12/14/2005  0.07    2/28/2006
115948  9/24/2004   0.13    9/30/2004
115948  9/24/2004   0.13    10/31/2004
115948  11/1/2004   0.09    11/30/2004
115948  11/1/2004   0.09    12/31/2004
115948  11/1/2004   0.09    1/31/2005
115948  2/2/2005    0.06    2/28/2005
115948  2/2/2005    0.06    3/31/2005
115948  2/2/2005    0.06    4/30/2005
115948  5/16/2005   0.04    5/31/2005
115948  5/16/2005   0.04    6/30/2005
115948  5/16/2005   0.04    7/31/2005
```

Note that record `115948    9/24/2004   0.13` gets upsampled only twice because the next available date is `11/1/2004`, which generates month_date of `11/30/2004` in the upsampled set.

Tried applying resample on groupby dataframe:

```
newdf=df.groupby(['UserID']).resample("M",fill_method='ffill')
```

but this does not produce the desired result. Any guidance/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post actual code to create the sample data. There are a lot of things relevant to your question that cannot be deduced from your vague description of the dataframe.

Comment: I dont understand last 2 rows of output `df`, how you get it. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df_dg = pd.DataFrame(dict(
     UserID=[11590] * 3 + [115948] * 4,
     Date=[20050613, 20050905, 20051214,
                    20040924, 20041101, 20050202,20050516],
      Characteristic=[0.06, 0.09, 0.07, 0.13, 0.09, 0.06, 0.04]), columns=['UserID','Date','Characteristic'])


df_dg['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dg['Date'], format="%Y%m%d")
print df_dg
   UserID       Date  Characteristic
0   11590 2005-06-13            0.06
1   11590 2005-09-05            0.09
2   11590 2005-12-14            0.07
3  115948 2004-09-24            0.13
4  115948 2004-11-01            0.09
5  115948 2005-02-02            0.06
6  115948 2005-05-16            0.04


df_dg['Date1'] = df_dg['Date']

newdf = df_dg.groupby('UserID').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Date').resample('M', how='first',fill_method='ffill')).reset_index(drop=True, level=0).reset_index()
newdf = newdf.rename(columns={'Date':'month_date', 'Date1':'Date'})
newdf = newdf[['UserID','Date','Characteristic','month_date']]
```

```
print newdf
    UserID       Date  Characteristic month_date
0    11590 2005-06-13            0.06 2005-06-30
1    11590 2005-06-13            0.06 2005-07-31
2    11590 2005-06-13            0.06 2005-08-31
3    11590 2005-09-05            0.09 2005-09-30
4    11590 2005-09-05            0.09 2005-10-31
5    11590 2005-09-05            0.09 2005-11-30
6    11590 2005-12-14            0.07 2005-12-31
7   115948 2004-09-24            0.13 2004-09-30
8   115948 2004-09-24            0.13 2004-10-31
9   115948 2004-11-01            0.09 2004-11-30
10  115948 2004-11-01            0.09 2004-12-31
11  115948 2004-11-01            0.09 2005-01-31
12  115948 2005-02-02            0.06 2005-02-28
13  115948 2005-02-02            0.06 2005-03-31
14  115948 2005-02-02            0.06 2005-04-30
15  115948 2005-05-16            0.04 2005-05-31
```

Comment: jezrael, great, thanks so much...this seems to be working...i knew that i am doing smth wrong with resample syntax. Apparently, for resample to work it is crucial to set the date index within the group first before i can apply resample method. Do you think if i were to set the date index to the groupby frame object first (smth like df_dg.groupby('UserID').set_index('Date') and then use .resample with it, would that work? I am not 100% sure i understand the apply method in your example...Thanks again

Comment: I think you have to use `set_index` in `apply`, because `resample` only works with `DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex`. And `apply` is very easy - it means get groups and `apply` some function. Very often are using `lambda`.